# Unity (in PRISM) does (not) weird resolving...??!!

Tags: unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I 'm  using PRISM and in the Bootstrapper class i did override the ConfigureContainer() method. There is nothing fancy in it just these lines:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{       
    Container.RegisterType<IDataContext, SQLDataContext>(new InjectionConstructor(@"Server=localhost\SQLExpress;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxx;Database=MyDatabase"));
        base.ConfigureContainer();
}
```

At "debug-time" i try to call Container.Resolve() but this gives me the following error:

> {"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = \"Photo.DAL.Abstract.IDataContext\", name = \"\". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Photo.DAL.Concrete.SQLDataContext, null]) failed: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: stream (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)"}    System.Exception {Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException}

But when i do

```
Container.IsTypeRegistered(typeof(IDataContext))
```

I get true!!!

- What am I missing???

---

**Info which published as answer below, which should be an edit to the question:**

This is the full stack:

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Photo.DAL.Abstract.IDataContext", name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Photo.DAL.Concrete.SQLDataContext, null]) failed: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3) ---> Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Photo.DAL.Concrete.SQLDataContext, null]) failed: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3) ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.XmlMappingSource.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at Photo.DAL.Mapping.GetMapping() in C:\Users\Savvas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Photo\Photo.DAL\Mapping.cs:line 18
   at Photo.DAL.Concrete.SQLDataContext..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\Users\Savvas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Photo\Photo.DAL\Concrete\SQLDataContext.cs:line 52
   at BuildUp_Photo.DAL.Concrete.SQLDataContext(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.Builder.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetime, IPolicyList policies, IStrategyChain strategies, Object buildKey, Object existing)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerBase.Resolve(Type t)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerBase.Resolve[T]()
   at Photo.Desktop.Bootstrapper.ConfigureContainer() in C:\Users\Savvas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Photo\Photo.Desktop\Bootstrapper.cs:line 42
```

I noticed that the error is not coming from actually resolving the class, but from the calling method GetMapping() which is defined as

```
public static class Mapping
    {
        public static XmlMappingSource GetMapping()
        {
            XmlMappingSource mapping;
            using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Photo.DAL.Entities.Entities.map"))
            {
                mapping = XmlMappingSource.FromStream(stream);
            }
            return mapping;
        }
    }
```

- Is Unity incapable of doing this? (it worked well with Windsor!!)

Comment: :( For extremely confusing title!

Comment: Yes you are right...but i'm confused also! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be one of two things.. it's not clear from your exception exactly...

1. Likely there is another inner
   exception that might be masked?
2. Otherwise it *might* be that your
   SqlDataContext class has a
   constructor that accepts a stream?

Again, the exception isn't quite clear enough (at least to me).  If neither of these suggestions helps, could you post the full out put of $exception.ToString() in your question?

***Edit:*** according to your full stack trace, the line of code failing is this one:

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.
                       GetExecutingAssembly().
                       GetManifestResourceStream("Photo.DAL.Entities.Entities.map"))
{
    //This line is failing with null argument
    mapping = XmlMappingSource.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Your resource stream is coming back null, which either indicates your resource does not exist or the assembly couldn't be loaded (sometimes this refers to a satellite assembly).  I would suspect the former first... check to make sure the Build setting is correct on your .map file.